# Sonata Admin, 2 variables, one survivor

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I've actually a problem with Sonata Admin bundle. When I want to display 2 variables from the same foreign table, I've just one variable displayed. I have this code:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('image', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'KayserPlatformBundle:ProductImage',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'Nom Image'
        ))
        ->add('image', 'entity', array(
        'class'    => 'KayserPlatformBundle:ProductImage',
        'property' => 'url',
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'Url'
        ))
    ;
}
```

How I can display the both?

Answer (score 0):

The field name (image) must be unique within the group. Otherwise the existing field is overwritten.